# Can I upgrade my VMware 6.0.3 without losing my data? I already upgraded to Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, vmware

I have VMWare Fusion 6.0.3 and I upgraded to Yosemite. Oops. I can't open VM because its not a compatible version. Can I still upgrade the VM without losing my data?? I really need to NOT lose my data. Note: I did not backup my computer before this...

Comment: Not that it helps, but I know Parallels upgrades without impact to data. I also recommend that you contact VMWare support.

Answer (score 1):

I know that when I upgraded VMWare to 7.0 after my Yosemite 10.10 upgrade I did not experience any problem with loss of data in my VMs.  After upgrading VMWare, the app did reconfigure the .vmwaremv files, but after that everything was the same.

I do not store data exterior to the VMs and I think that all my data is within the .vmwarevm itself.  Like the other user pointed out, contact VMWare to be sure.  Hope this helps.  Just my experience is all...